# How to assign a unique text per group of entries in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of employees in Column A and a location in Column b(empty). I need to assign a location  for every twenty  employees  which its value on another sheet on column a. thanks

Comment: You needed to [edit your first question](http://superuser.com/q/1071293/97028) so it can be reopened. Just posting another poorly formatted question isn't helping. This one has too little detail of what you have attempted and where you are stuck. Again, please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I place the locations in column **F**.

In **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(F$1:F$14,ROUNDUP(ROW()/20,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

If your locations are in a different sheet, then modify the reference column in the formula.

Comment: i will thank you greatly before i try it  ,again am grateful for your response

Comment: MAY I ASK IF THE I WANT TO CHANGE THE CAPACITY OF EACH LOCATION FOR EXAMPLE  Adrastes 20 people and Aitne 25 ...etc   what the function will be used (vlookup ? ) . thanks

Comment: @Rami  an interesting request!

Comment: @Rami  *VLOOKUP()* will work see: [fixer1234]( http://www.superuser.com/questions/1071351/generating-repeating-data)

Comment: Thank you........ for your time and effort , i really appreciate your patience and understanding ......Rami