# Generating Repeating Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 4 data items in column **B**.  Initially I needed to fill another column with the original data repeated 7 times.  So the first item should appear 7 times, then the second item should then appear 7 times, etc.

In **A1** I entered:

```
=INDEX(B$1:B$4,ROUNDUP(ROW()/7,0),0)
```

and copied down:

[image]

The small formula appears to work just fine.  Now I need to generate the second column, but rather than 7 repetitions, use a set values in column **C**.

I have done this with a short macro:

```
Sub Repititions()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, v As String
    Dim M As Long, K As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 1
    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, "B").Value
        M = Cells(i, "C").Value
        For j = 1 To M
            Cells(K, "D").Value = v
            K = K + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

This also works.....there are 3 alphas, 7 betas, etc.

My question is can I get this variable repeating factor using a formula rather than a VBA sub ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach using a helper column:

[image: screenshot]

Column A is the starting row for each value.

```
A1:  1
A2:  =A1+C1
etc.
```

The results are in column E.  Cell E1:

```
=VLOOKUP(ROW(),A$1:B$4,2)
```

With the row ranges defined, you can do a simple VLOOKUP for the value in each row.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: I suspect you were just too close to your own problem.  :-)

Comment: You are correct.............I kept trying to replace the **7** in the original formula with some function of *ROW()*.  Your approach is WAY better.